# Bash issue with floating point numbers in specific format

Tags: linux, awk, grep

(Need in bash linux)I have a file with numbers like this

```
1.415949602
91.09582241
91.12042924
91.40270349
91.45625033
91.70150341
91.70174342
91.70660043
91.70966213
91.72597066
91.7287678315
91.7398645966
91.7542977976
91.7678146465
91.77196659
91.77299733
abcdefghij
91.7827827
91.78288651
91.7838959
91.7855
91.79080605
91.80103075
91.8050505

sed 's/^91\.//' file (working)
```

Any way possible I can do these 3 steps?

1st I try this

```
cat input | tr -d 91. > 1.txt (didnt work) 
cat input | tr -d "91." > 1.txt (didnt work) 
cat input | tr -d '91.' > 1.txt (didnt work)
```

then

```
grep -x '.\{10\}' (working)
```

then

```
grep "^[6-9]" (working)
```

Final 1 line solution

```
cat input.txt | sed 's/\91.//g' | grep -x '.\{10\}'  | grep "^[6-9]" > output.txt
```

Comment: What code have _you_ written to solve this and where exactly are you facing issues?

Comment: On SO we encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problem, so kindly add so and let us know then.

Comment: Just to note, *none* of those numbers have length 10, unless you are replacing a leading `91.` with `0.` rather than just removing `91`. (And in that case, none of them would start with 6, 7, 8 or 9.)

Comment: @chepner it was a sample of a long file I add few 10 digits number

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Please refresh

Comment: @ForceBru please refresh

Comment: @Priyanka, Good that you have shown your efforts,could you please post samples more clearly also in your question and let us know then?

Comment: `tr -d 91.` will remove all `9`s, `1`s, and `.`s from the input, regardless of where they occur. It doesn't remove the specific string `91.`.

Comment: All of this should be a single Awk script. Examine `sub()` in the documentation and learn the basics of regular expressions so you don't have to guess so wildly.

Comment: `sed` might do, `sed -E 's/^91\.//; /^[0-9]{10}$/!{/^[0-9]+$/d}; /^[0-5][0-9]*$/d'`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/VbIm6T).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew when i run it show me sed: 1: "s/^91\.//; /^[0-9]{10}$ ...": extra characters at the end of d command

Comment: @tripleee whats the sub() meaning ?

Comment: @Priyanka So, you do not have a GNU sed then, you need `-e` syntax then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew do you want me to replace -E to -e ? (didnt work) . or both (didnt work that too)

Comment: No, changing `E` with `e` makes no sense. You need to study your `sed` implementation if you want to use `sed` solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I sort out last 2 part, only getting rid off "91." is last, could you please only help with it (please check question again, i updated)

Comment: @chepner I got your point, could you please help me for getting rid off "91." thanks

Comment: Removing `91.` is basic, `sed 's/^91\.//' file`

Comment: Pro tip: include a context word in the search query. I literally googled "awk sub" and that was my top result.

Comment: @tripleee no, what I search is "how"   .. "how to remove a text in a file in linux " , "how to grep a line in linux based on length" and so on...  the problem with pro, they consider everyone else pro or assume that everyone become pro...   I am not everyday programmer... I got problem I will solve and back to other work...

Comment: So, what's the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "final" solution:

```
cat input.txt |
sed 's/\91.//g' |
grep -x '.\{10\}' |
grep "^[6-9]" > output.txt
```

should avoid the [useless `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat), and also move the backslash in the `sed` script to the correct place (and I added a `^` anchor and removed the `g` flag since you don't expect more than one match on a line anyway);

```
sed 's/^91\.//' input.txt |
grep -x '.\{10\}' |
grep "^[6-9]" > output.txt
```

You might also be able to get rid of at least one [useless `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) but at this point, I would switch to Awk:

```
awk '{ sub(/^91\./, "") } /^[6-9].{9}$/' input.txt >output.txt
```

The `sub()` does what your `sed` replacement did; the final condition says to print lines which match the regex.

The  same can conveniently, but less readably, be written in `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/^91\.([6-9][0-9]\{9\}\)$/\1/p' input.txt >output.txt
```

assuming your `sed` dialect supports BRE regex with repetitions like `[0-9]\{9\}`.